# Extra things while executing the jps command

Tags: java, hadoop

I was running a word count program on 100GB text file.I use 3 systems in a multi node cluster mater, slave1 and slave 2. other than master 2 slaves run data node and task tracker respectively. Now when I run the jps commend on slave machines it will slow the following output:

```
hduser@slave2:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$  jps
2970 DataNode
6456 Child
14534 RunJar
6529 Jps
3215 TaskTracker
5787 Child
6463 Child
```

Now what is here child???
What do you mean by RunJar?

Comment: Thanks for reply. sir i thought to send the question you have formatted. But i was not able to send in that format from hduser@slave2:...and so on how to actually send in that format??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason behind the jps command slowness is that the slave node is being used for the execution of mapreduce task. During mapreduce execution resources like CPU, memory etc. would be almost utilized by mapreduce tasks as a result commmand execution will take some time.

- What is RunJar ? 
  When you execute `hadoop jar <Jarname>` command from a node, Hadoop Runjar utility main Class `org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar` will be invoked.
- Wat is Child 
  The TaskTracker executes the Mapper/Reducer task as a child process in a separate jvm. Child java processes belog to either map taks or reduce tasks

Use the option `jps -l` for getting the complete Packagename & Classname